# InternetQueryOption, INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION and the INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS_UI flag

Tags: c, windows, winapi, wininet

I am writing a program which queries proxy settings using the InternetQueryOption API.

Looking through the Windows docs for `INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385145%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

There is a note in the docs

> **Windows 7 and later:**
>   Clients that support Internet Explorer 8 should query the connection type using INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS_UI. If this query fails, then the system is running a previous version of Internet Explorer and the client should query again with INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS.
>
> Restore the connection type using INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS regardless of the version of Internet Explorer.

I have tested using `INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS` instead of `INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS_UI` on a Win7 64 bit machine running IE9 & everything seems to work fine.

Also the documentation for functionality of `INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS` and `INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS_UI` seems identical.

So what is the reason for using `INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS_UI`? Does the note suggest that it is only of IE8 or for IE8 & greater.

My program needs to support everything from WinXP running IE6 to current Win7 machines. So I am not clear as to what I should use.

This is my code

```
INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST    List;
INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION         Option[1];
unsigned long                    nSize = sizeof(INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST);

Option[0].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;

List.dwSize = sizeof(INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST);
List.pszConnection = 0;
List.dwOptionCount = sizeof(Option)/sizeof(Option[0]);
List.dwOptionError = 0;

Option[0].Value.pszValue = 0;

List.pOptions = Option;

InternetQueryOption(NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, &List, &nSize);
```

1. Should I change `INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS` to `INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS_UI` & then again call with `INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS` in case `INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS_UI` fails?
2. Also what exactly does this mean

   > Restore the connection type using INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS regardless of the version of Internet Explorer.

Does this mean `INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS_UI` is relevant only for `InternetQueryOption` and for `InternetSetOption`, I should be always using `INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS`.

Answer (score 2):

INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS_UI returns the proxy settings as shown inside Tools > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings.

These settings may differ from the settings returned by INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS, which will "hide" the "automatically detect" setting if WinINET believes that the current network does not use WPAD. This is a performance optimization, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5138232/126229 for more information.

Generally speaking, you should only use INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS_UI when displaying settings to the user; use INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS if your goal is to determine what proxy should be used.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation you quoted and the description of what you want to achieve, it seems to me that the answers to your questions 1 and 2 are `Yes` and `Yes`.

However, as with all MS documentation, it can be unclear, outdated, or just plain wrong. So I would recommend that you start with the assumptions you outlined in your question and test a prototype of your code on various combinations of platforms WinXP/IE6, Win8/IE10 etc. using VMs. Doing it empirically is probably going to give you a much better idea of what the real facts are vs the documentation and will also provide you with some test environments for further work.